# Min number of matching nested docs should be atleast n in ES 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index called campus which contains the resume as a nested mapping in them.

resume has fields like courseID, specId, passingYear etc.
When queried on resume fields, I want to return those campus which have n such matching resume.

For example I want to return those campus which have atleast 20 students where each student should be of BTech(CourseID) and IT(specId) and should be graduating in 2024.

How can I achieve this in ES 7.5

I tried script query on nested but I keep getting ctx as null

Comment: hi there, please also share what you did in script query and output result